# Sending data into the nearest web server in a city using two given coordinates. client and server coordinates

Tags: php, android, coordinates

How do I send my data from my android app using the coordinates of my location and the data will be sent into the nearest webserver . it's like every web server has given coordinates.
PS * i will develop both sides server and phone.

thankyou in advance! :) sorry if my question is not very clear

Answer (score 0):

You question is clear, but to send something to a server, you need at least informations about.
you can not send data to a server just by having coordinates.

regards

Comment: what I will do is i will the develop both system the phone and the server. :) the algorithm would appear in android side. its like if the coordinates is near to the compared web server coordinates it will be sent there

Comment: Okay then it's possible, just need to develop the right algorithm ;)

Comment: what algorithm? and do you have a sample ?

Comment: i don't have any sample unfortunately, but you need to develop the algorithm that is gonna tell you what is the nearest web server ..